# Change Glog logging directory of linked library

Tags: shared-libraries, glog

I have an application that uses Glog. I can use environmental variables or Gflags to change the logging directory of this application. In this application, I link to another library that also uses Glog. The way I changed the directory of the application logging does not also change the logging directory of this linked library. Does anyone know of how to change the Glog logging directory of a linked library?

EDIT:

In my main executable for the application, I begin with:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
...}
```

An environmental variable GLOG_log_dir is set to a folder in my application directory. Immediately, I can start using things like this line from my main executable:

```
if(!FLAGS_localizer) {
    LOG(INFO) << "Localizer not initialized. To initialize, use parameter -localizer";
}
```

When I go to my specified log folder, I see a file like `gui.engr2-13-197-dhcp.int.colorado.edu.username.log.INFO.20160511-124903.19677` that contains all the `LOG(INFO)` calls in my application. Now I have one linked library (a communication sublayer) that contains Glog calls and these calls are all correctly written to that same `..log.INFO...` file I could look at above. Since the logging is coming from different files, the log file looks like this:

```
I0511 12:49:03.570866 1955471360 gui.cpp:31] Localizer not initialized. To initialize, use parameter -localizer
```

from my main executable and like this:

```
I0511 12:49:08.030144 1955471360 Node.cpp:1050] Found 1 URLs for nodes
I0511 12:49:08.030184 1955471360 Node.cpp:1057] node at 10.201.13.197:5555
I0511 12:49:08.030200 1955471360 Node.cpp:1085] Connecting to 10.201.13.197:5555
I0511 12:49:08.030308 1955471360 Node.cpp:1095] 'MochaGui' connected to remote node: 10.201.13.197:5555
```

from my linked library that works. I have another linked library (the one causing the problem) that is linked in cmake in the same way as the working linked library, except *its* Glog calls are not written at all to this log file. I would expect them to look similar but have the header `[IO511 <time> Localizer.cpp:<lineNo>]`, instead of the same with "Node.cpp" (Node is the working linked library). For instance, I use my (non-working) linked library to initialize a Localizer like this:

```
Localizer::Localizer()
{
    //FLAGS_log_dir = "/Users/username/Documents/ARPGDependencies/MochaGui/logs";
    //google::InitGoogleLogging("Localizer");
    m_bIsStarted = false;
    m_pNode = new node::node;
    m_pNode->init("commander_node");
    if( m_pNode->advertise("command") == false ){
        LOG(ERROR) << "Error setting up publisher.";
    }
    LOG(INFO) << "New Localizer created.";
}
```

I tried to manually set the log directory for this particular object, but those lines are commented out because it did not have any effect. I know this constructor is being called because I call it in my application header file like this:

```
Localizer m_Localizer;
```

But the `LOG(INFO) << "New Localizer created.";` cannot be found anywhere in the log files that are being created. So my question is, how do I get *this* library to output its Glog statements to the same file as the rest of the application? I've also combed the source for each linked library and found no differences in how Glog is included and used. In both, `#include <glog/logging.h>` is called, and then Glog `LOG(<severity>)` calls are immediately used.

Comment: What did you try so far. Please post your code and we'll be glad to help!

Comment: In addition, all Glog says is that by default, all log files write to a temporary directory, but looking through my Glog source turns up no directories that I can find. And adding the flag --logtostderr=1 does not change the fact that my linked library does not write to the same place as the rest of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a problem with the way QtCreator handles dependencies. It was not building the libraries to the correct directory when I updated them, so the executable was never built with the Glog statements in the first place.